# Google API Key results in permanent "loading..." message

Tags: google-api

I am trying to get Google API key for Google Search API but this is showing "loading..." permanently:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

[image]

Always showing same error:

[image]

Comment: Me too, 24 hours later and went back to work

Comment: @AmandaOsvaldo - what about your.. your issue is resolved?

Comment: In my case, it happened when my internet provider stopped sending me an IPv6 address. So i just restarted my internet router and have get a IPv6. If it not worked I whould have called to internet provider requering a IPv6 address

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happened when my internet provider stopped sending me an IPv6 address.

Maybe it's your case too.

Comment: I don't know how but today I try and my issue is resolved...... but still I don't know how this resolved...

Comment: Perhaps it's the same IPv6 problem. Or your browser cache. If occur again try in another browser and device ... and check if you have an IPv6 address. TIme ago I disabled IPv6 in my computer (not my in router) and some applications sopped to work.